# Access docker container from Local Area Network devices

Tags: docker

I’m brand new to docker; I am running docker desktop for Mac and I have a container with an IP `192.168.73.10`.

I set port forwarding to ports `80` and `443` during initial setup. I can access web service to this container from the local host (my Mac) just fine; however, all devices connected to my LAN are on a `10.20.0.0/24` subnet.

How exactly do I access the web service on the container from devices on my LAN (`10.20.0.0/24` subnet)? I have port `80` and `443` open on my Mac. Haven’t been able to find any helpful answers on the forum. Please help!

Comment: can you ping your Mac from your other device?

Comment: yes -- my mac can reach all devices (and vice versa) in my network and can also reach the container

Comment: do a netstat -an | grep 443 on your mac and see to which IP address the port has binded, since you say, you can ping form the LAN devices to the Mac means there is no routing issue between 2 networks. Ideally, you should be able to access both port 80 and 443, if not, try to isolate the issue with the network or docker environment i.e. stop the container, open a dummy session of port 80 with netcat and try to reach the dummy port 80 form a LAN device.

Comment: Does Mac have a firewall installed which maybe blocks traffic coming from external?

Answer (score 2):

It was actually a firewall issue on my network. Thanks for the suggestions and responses.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways. Lets say for example your started the container like this:

```
docker run --restart always -p 9017:80 -d --name organizr --net=my-bridge organizrtools/organizr-v2
```

In the above case you can connect to the site by the port `9017` since you exposed that port on your machine. So, if your machine's IP is for example `10.20.0.1` you'd use `http://10.20.0.1:9017`. You can use that from any machine on your LAN.

OR if you don't open up a port on your machine, and just go with the port setup within the container, you can call it by it's hostname, which by default is also the container's name.

So for example, you created the container like this:

```
docker run --restart always -d --name organizr --net=my-bridge organizrtools/organizr-v2
```

since the default port setup within the container is port `80`, you'd get to the page like this: `http://organizr:80`. That needs to be called from within one of your docker networks though.